# Create SQLAlchemy Column with Foreign Key

Tags: python, python-3.x, database, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I am currently adding new columns to existing (PostgreSQL) database tables using SQLAlchemy and the following Python code:

```py
from sqlalchemy import Column, ForeignKey, Integer, String

def add_column(engine, table_name, column):
    column_name = column.compile(dialect=engine.dialect)
    column_type = column.type.compile(engine.dialect)
    engine.execute('ALTER TABLE %s ADD COLUMN %s %s' % (table_name, column_name, column_type))

column = Column('city', String)
add_column(engine, 'homes', column)
```

However, when I try to add a column with a foreign key, as shown:

```py
column = Column('city', Integer, ForeignKey('cities.id'))
add_column(engine, 'homes', column)
```

the foreign key does not appear to be added.

How can we modify the `add_column` function to also allow for a foreign key to be specified when adding the new column?

Comment: Are you intentionally not using a migration tool such as [alembic](https://alembic.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/)?

Comment: @SuperShoot Kind of, this will likely be the only change to any table structure in the database of this project. Trying to avoid pulling in another dependency.

Comment: This is just my opinion, you can take it or leave it. Alembic is easy to set up, is a dev-dependency, not a runtime dependency and will save you from having to reinvent the wheel to get this done.